# Access denied: 'view published content' permission

Tags: routes

When I look into admin/people/permissions: 'View published content' is checked for anonymous users.

Yet the following code:

```
function test_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'access arguments' => 'view published content',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

returns 'Accessed denied' when I navigate to /test as an anonymous user. I know I can do:

```
'access callback' => TRUE,
```

but the other code seems a lot neater. I've experienced this issue a few times before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at [node_permissions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_permission/7) makes me think you should be using 'access content' as your argument, not view published content', as the latter is the proper machine name for the permission.